# INQUIRE: Replit took over github page. How to remove Repl from site

Tags: github-pages, replit

So i was trying to bind a replit project to my Github page, and now its taken over! I deleted the CNAME and TXT files on the root (sneslover22.github.io) but now my main site (sneslover22.github.io/Mathews-Collection) doesn't work! I also unlinked the repl from my domain, but i dont understand why its still there! is there more I have to do or something?

(note)

Please dont close this question because its asking for help. I dont know where else to go, and I don't want to lose all my stuff I worked hard for on my site.

I tried everything, from deleting the files(CNAME and TXT), unlinking my domain from replit, and also deleting the repl itself.